# Have a field on form that I cannot get rid of

Tags: netsuite

I have a field with no label that is showing on all of the sales order forms - including the standard form. Every time the form is saved an email error is sent that states the following:

```
Unexpected error: ERROR DETAILS
ex=JavaException: com.netledger.common.exceptions.NLUserError: The field custpage_dad_sublists contained more than the maximum number ( 300 ) of characters allowed.
RhinoException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.netledger.common.exceptions.NLUserError: The field custpage_dad_sublists contained more than the maximum number ( 300 ) of characters allowed. (dad-record-page-ue.js$3093#253)
Stack= at dad-record-page-ue.js$3093:253 (beforeLoad)
at dad-record-page-ue.js$3093:313
```

When I look at the XML for the form I see the following field:

```
<custpage_dad_sublists>["item","links","mediaitem","partners"]</custpage_dad_sublists>
```

Any ideas on how I can find this field or how I can get rid of this problem?

Netsuite is no help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can search that field by ctrl + shift + f then type internal id of the field .
You can go to customize form and check in sublist fields if that field has shown box unchecked .
You can go to transaction line fields and set maximum length of that field .

Answer (score 0):

The `_dad_` in the field id comes from the File Drag and Drop bundle. You could check for an update for the bundle or disable it for the time being.